# Bad motherboard

Tags: motherboard, post

I have an ECS P4VXASD2+ and it's really frustrating right now to see what is causing it to not POST. Throughout this entire time, there were 2x 512 MB PC-2100 DDR-266 SDRAM, one DVD-ROM, one CD-ROM, a generic 6 GB IDE HDD, an OKIA 300W PSU and a HIS Radeon X1650 512 MB AGP.

First I had a P4 2.8 GHz (FSB 533 MHz) and it wouldn't post, even though it has done so in the past. The CPU, RAM, HDD and GPU were not getting hot whatsoever. I double checked that the CPU was completely seated in the socket and same thing on the next boot up.

Next I had a P4 2.6 GHz (FSB 400 MHz) and adjusted the jumpers accordingly. The computer powered up and everything was getting hot, but no POST. Again, double checked everything so make sure they were properly seated and same thing next time around.

So, I really can't tell if it's just a bad motherboard; all capacitors appear to be fine. (There are probably some other things that I should be doing to double check that everything other than the motherboard is working well, but I don't readily have the resources.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check post, disconnect All hardware except for the PSU, Processor, video and 1 memory module. If it has onboard Video use that, if you are using a Add in video card, try another one.

Comment: I never found a solution to this problem as I ended up selling the board as-is. Still, this is something that I usually do to troubleshoot these types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the battery on your motherboard (it's silver, size of a nickel) has a charge.   If not, then you may need to replace the battery and get the BIOS chip reflashed/replaced.

Comment: CMOS doesn't (usually) cause things not to post.

Comment: CMOS battery is brand new! I checked that a while ago and had a question a while ago when the computer USED to POST, but would take at least 10-15 seconds before it did.